# Upgraded RoR application (2 to 3.2) handles form input strangely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If have a RoR application that I upgraded from 2 to 3.2, and everything eventually got fixed, but I have some strange behavior from a form_tag.

The form code is:

```
<%= form_tag '/public/checkem' do %>
   <%= hidden_field "vals", value = picks.draw %>
   <%= hidden_field "val_index", value = xcount %>
   <%= submit_tag picks.draw_date %>
<% end %>
```

Where picks.draw is an array which, when executed in turn generates:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/public/checkem" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ET8OgURJpwvnQ+18lK1xKaFXTBLMuMXVw4AoM/gVEYw=" /></div>
    <input id="vals_6,16,45,54,60,15" name="vals[6,16,45,54,60,15]" type="hidden" />
    <input id="val_index_5" name="val_index[5]" type="hidden" />
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="10/25/2013" />
</form>
```

The idea being that the hidden input (vals) contains an array of numbers.  This value is then processed correctly as an array in the /public/checkem function, but when it gets re-rendered here:

```
  <span class="elem" style="background-color: #b0b040; color: #000000;"><%=@xpicks[0]%></span>
```

where @xpicks[0] is the first element of the array

```
<span class="elem" style="background-color: #b0b040; color: #000000;">{&quot;2</span>
```

It's picked up what looks like the start of a hash.  When I look in the log file I see this line, which confirms that the array was changed to a hash when the form was submitted:

```
Processing by PublicController#checkem as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?", "authenticity_token"=>"ET8OgURJpwvnQ+18lK1xKaFXTBLMuMXVw4AoM/gVEYw=", "vals"=>{"2,11,42,64,74,2"=>""}, "val_index"=>{"1"=>""}, "commit"=>"11/05/2013"}
```

This all worked fine in version 2, but I cannot see where, or why the array gets passed as a hash.

Comment: not exactly sure what you are trying to do but maybe this will help? `<%= hidden_field "vals[]", picks.draw %>` - use `[]` at the end of the input field name, this will cause rails to automatically convert that to to an array stored in `params[:vals]`

Comment: doing that just throws an error: `ActionView::Template::Error (object[] naming but object param and @object var don't exist or don't respond to to_param: nil):`

Comment: Well, I finally got around the problem but it's a bit kludgy.  Basically I replaced the line that accepts the param from `@xpicks = params[:vals].to_s.split(",")` to `@xpicks = params[:vals].to_s.split('"')[1].split(",")`, which works but I should be able to pass arrays properly, no?

Comment: I've realized that the "picks.draw" variable is not even an array, it's just a string containing comma-delimited numbers like "1,2,3,4,5", which makes it even weirder that the the hidden_field is performing this translation on it.

Comment: OK.  Figured it out I should have been using "hidden_field_tag" not "hidden_field", that way the string is preserved.  hidden_field is supposed to be used when a model and a form_for is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the use of "hidden_field" is indicated when a model and "form_for" is used.  If there is no model you should use "hidden_field_tag"